# How to make text look like readable English but is actually illegible?

Tags: fonts, text

I’m looking to obfuscate some text by making it completely illegible.
While this is very easy to do in handwriting, I need it to be done on a webpage in Verdana.

I was thinking that I could possibly make a Verdana-esque font that has the top and bottom halves of many letters switched, or I could overlap lines of text such that it becomes an unreadable mess.

I could just replace text with a keyboard mash, except that is clearly a keyboard mash, when I want it to look obfuscated.

What are possible ways to go about this?

Comment: I don't understand why a usjse of jselkas for occassional wsijaj woalsjn't sulassdops.

Comment: Because it's very clear that that's random letters. I need the reader to be unable to distinguish between English and nonsense - that is clearly nonsense.

Comment: Well all English readers will **immediately** know something is "nonsense" regardless of your method. I suppose you could randomly insert actual words making sentences mean nothing, but that would all need to be done manually most likely.

Comment: How about some javascript to shuffle the words randomly? There's a question with answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3943772/how-do-i-shuffle-the-characters-in-a-string-in-javascript

Comment: Check this http://www.blindtextgenerator.com/lorem-ipsum It has also random English.

Comment: do you still want the english words to be there or you just want to use the characters to make random words? If the first then fred_dot_u's answer might work for you.

Answer (score 5):

The standard approach in Graphic Design for what (I think) you are trying to achieve is to use ‘latin’ aka ‘Lorem ipsum’. This generates a block of text that has statistically similar word lengths and sentence structure to English using words that are readable and made up of English characters, but it is complete and utter nonsense. It looks like this:

> Phasellus augue justo, porta eu lacus ac, egestas volutpat lorem. Cras elementum at nibh ut sollicitudin. Pellentesque venenatis dolor et massa suscipit maximus. Donec in lacus pellentesque, luctus turpis non, fermentum metus. Nulla egestas justo non eros porttitor, sodales ullamcorper nisl consequat. Quisque a ultricies ligula. Praesent cursus arcu nec leo rutrum suscipit.

My favourite place for more information and the generator that I always use when I need some Latin is https://lipsum.com

If you are wanting to replace text in an existing page then I imagine it would be quite straightforward to write a bit of JavaScript to replace a given string of English with the same number of characters / words of Lorem Ipsum.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is phrased in such a manner as to indicate you want a graphics image, not a manipulation of text that would be created via web coding. If your objective will be solved with a graphics image (.png, for example), you can create that which you need with a graphics editing program that supports text. Inkscape comes to mind, which then follows that Illustrator will also work. I believe I can accomplish your objective using Paint Shop Pro, my preferred raster editor, while others may find Photoshop or GIMP to be of their liking.

[image: obfuscated text image]

The image above is a cut and paste of your question, with random placement of randomly selected lines. It was accomplished in Inkscape by pasting the text into a text field, converting it to a path, ungrouping the components and selecting blocks of lines of text and dragging them into position. The result was exported as a .png file and uploaded here.

[image: obfuscated image 2]

I like this one better. It's a single line, mirrored in the vertical plane, although I suspect it could be done horizontally, then planted over the original. You can just make out the I'm at the beginning and end, but beyond that it's obfuscated. If you know that it reads "I'm looking to obfuscate some" you can pull out the shapes, but even that isn't done easily.

Comment: I can still read most of it though

Comment: I did not go to great extremes to obfuscate completely the sample. One could easily make it completely illegible by moving lines closer together or double-reversing/mirroring the text or any number of modifications. The intent of my answer was to provide a workflow suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Actually this is presented already in comments to some degree, but simply cutting and pasting non-linearly some existing text can be enough, if the subject of the text isn't especially familiar to the readers. The following text was at first a direct copy. Then some words, and phrases were cut and pasted to elsewhere until all lines had one cut and paste or two. The positions of capital letters, spaces and punctuation marks were tried to preserve.

===

I’m looking what possible are to go about this? To obfuscate some text handwriting by making it I could just. While this is very easy to do in, I need it to be done text with a keyboard on. What possible ways are webpage in Verdana?

I was thinking that replace mash, except it mess becomes an unreadable, is clearly overlap lines of a keyboard mash, when I want it text such that I could possibly make a Verdana-esque font that completely halves illegible has the top and bottom  of many switched letters, or I could look to obfuscated.

Actually and paste or two this is presented already until all lines had one in comments to some degree, but simply cutting and pasting non-linearly some existing text can be enough and phrase were cut. If the subject of the text isn't  to the readers. The following text was at first especially familiar a direct copy. Then some words, and pasted to elsewhere cut .